# Pusher is not working on Production server- Laravel Broadcasting

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, laravel-5.4, pusher

Hi i am trying to up and running pusher on production server but it is only logging events to logs.

here are my settings for this

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=myappid
PUSHER_APP_KEY=myappkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=myappsecret
```

here is broadcasting.php

```
  'default' => 'pusher',


'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' =>'eu'
        ],
    ],
```

Broadcast service provider is also uncommented

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

but it is still logging events to log i dont know why is there a solution. it is working fine on local

Comment: if you run `php artisan tinker` on your prod server and type `config('broadcasting');`. Do you see the correct settings?

Comment: @Robert i am getting log as a setting how is this possible even i have hard coded default to pusher?

Comment: Probably cache in `bootstrap/cache/`, try doing a `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laravel caches the config in the `bootstrap/cache/` directory, you can check this by doing:

```
$ php artisan tinker
```

And output the current config with:

```
config('broadcasting');
```

Now you see what Laravel uses for config.

If that is different than your config file or .env or env, perform:

```
$ php artisan config:clear
```

---

If you want to prevent this in the future, do a `config:clear` after deploying your code.